# What does the community team think about our site?

Tags: discussion, site-health

It's been [about two years](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/749/what-can-we-do-to-improve-findability) since the last time the community team weighed in publicly on how they felt the Japanese site was doing (as far as I was able to find).  There was a brief discussion in a [podcast three years ago](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/se-podcast-28-brent-ozar/) where Joel was a bit skeptical that these language sites would even work out, but other than that, we've just been chugging along in beta.

We've gone through a few self-evalations now with results that rate us slightly above satisfactory.  Some sites older than ours have been closed down for inactivity.  Some sites newer than ours have fully launched.  I don't think we're doing so poorly we're in immediate risk of being shut down (or else we'd probably see a topic from Grace Note warning us to clean up the site), but we also don't have the explosive traffic and excitement that [some of the newer sites do](http://workplace.stackexchange.com), so my guess is we're still in the "meh, okay" zone.

Still, I think it would be helpful to [check in with the community team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223281/is-there-any-way-to-request-official-feedback-on-what-to-do-in-order-to-graduate) and make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: Incidentally, german.SE and french.SE have very similar stats and been around for almost exactly the same amount of time.

Comment: One thing that might affect Japanese Language's health is if Stack Overflow in non-English languages goes well. If a Stack Overflow in Japanese goes well, then maybe some of those users will start participating in other stack exchanges, even those that are conducted in English, such as the Japanese Language stack exchange.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What does the team think about your site?

**You're on the road to graduation**.

The only thing stopping you from graduating has been on our end - namely that we haven't had a site design prepared. Until recent months, Jin has been overworked by us as our only designer on the site end of things. In charge of handling not just the creation of the designs, but also handling design bugs across the entire network. And we've just been piling a lot of sites on his plate - this site being one of them. Now that we have more hands to do the job, we're starting to plow through this backlog.

I don't have an estimate as to when this site will be reached out of the queue, but when it does, there will be a new post here proposing the design ideas.

Comment: I've never participated in a beta site so I have a question: is a preview of the design going to happen? Is the community going to have some input into the design?

Comment: @Szymon Yes. It will take some time but basically, when they've got a preliminary design ready, the designers will come to your Meta here and present it for your review. The feedback you give will help shape how the final product comes out.